# How to change div content with using other div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem about changing div content. My form has a selectbox for regions. The options are Philippines and United States. The logic is if the user select the Philippines. The textbox below the selecbox will be automatically replace by other div that has a selectbox also. And if the user select United States or no selection it will just display the textbox below. By default there's a textbox below the selection box. Here's my code.

```
<label style="font-weight: normal">Country</label>
<select style="width: 250px" name="region_country" id="region_country">
    <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
</select>
<label style="font-weight: normal">Region</label><br />
<div id="region_selection_text">
    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" id="region" name="region" />
</div>
<div id="region_selector_selection">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In my jquery I have this.

```
$("#region_country").on('change',function(){

    var region = $("#region_country").val();

    if(region == 'Philippines'){

        //display selectbox here

    } else {

        //display textbox here if no selection or if the selection is United States

    }

});
```

My solution is creating a hide and show functions for it. Or are there any way to achieve this? As you have seen there are two divs  below the label Region. The first div is for textbox and the second div is for selectbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .toggle() like

```
var $rt = $('#region_selection_text'),
    $rs = $('#region_selector_selection');
$("#region_country").on('change', function () {
    var isP = this.value == 'Philippines'
    $rt.toggle(!isP);
    $rs.toggle(isP);
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U9Pfw/)